# Thread.join not working

Tags: java, multithreading

A call to join() Guaranteed to cause the current thread to stop executing until the thread it joins with
(in other words, the thread it calls join() on) completes.

**However, in my program both the threads are executing simultaneously. Thread1 is not waiting for Thread2 to finish its execution.**

**What is wrong with my program?**

```
public class Launcher1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JoinExample runnable=new JoinExample();

        Thread thread1=new Thread(runnable);
        Thread thread2=new Thread(runnable);

        thread1.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        thread2.start();
        try {
            thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public class JoinExample implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("i:"+i+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> > Output:
> >
> > i:0 Thread-0
> >
> > i:1 Thread-0
> >
> > i:0 Thread-1
> >
> > i:2 Thread-0
> >
> > i:1 Thread-1
> >
> > i:3 Thread-0
> >
> > i:4 Thread-0
> >
> > i:2 Thread-1
> >
> > i:3 Thread-1
> >
> > i:5 Thread-0
> >
> > i:4 Thread-1
> >
> > i:6 Thread-0
> >
> > i:7 Thread-0
> >
> > i:5 Thread-1
> >
> > i:8 Thread-0
> >
> > i:6 Thread-1
> >
> > i:7 Thread-1
> >
> > i:9 Thread-0
> >
> > i:8 Thread-1
>
> i:9 Thread-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, in my program both the threads are executing simultaneously. Thread1 is not waiting for Thread2 to finish its execution.

No, and it wouldn't - because thread 1 isn't calling `join`. Look at the docs you quoted again:

> A call to join() Guaranteed to cause the **current thread** to stop executing until the thread it joins with

To put it another way: the `join()` method doesn't finish until the thread it's called on has finished.

You've got *three* threads in your program - two that are running `JoinExample.run`, and the "main" thread that starts the other two. You're telling that *main* thread to wait for thread 2 to finish, but that's all. Your two `JoinExample` threads are entirely independent.

Answer (score 2):

There are three threads in question here.
1st thread - main thread, which runs the main method and spawns the 2 child threads.
2nd thread - `thread1`
3rd thread - `thread2`
When you say `thread2.join()`, the main thread will block until `thread2` finishes,`thread1` and `thread2` will continue to run.